# View Animation above or below edittext dynamically

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I make one application in which I need to animate view above or below EditText, when EditText is top of the screen , view should be animate below the EditText , when EditText is bottom of screen the view should be animate above the EditText

need help, any link or tutorial appreciated

Comment: what kind of animation??

Comment: view animation from top to bottom or bottom to top

Answer (score 0):

Please use the **TranslateAnimation** with from (x,y) and to (x,y) and get your edit text position using **yourView.getLocationInWindow()**. 
I hope this will help you.

Comment: do you have any demo or link or any tutorial ??

Comment: Please use the following sample code:                          public void locateAndLoadAnimation(View view) {
  int locations[] = new int[2];
  txtSample.getLocationInWindow(locations);
  Log.d(TAG, "Location1: " + locations[0] + " Location2: " + locations[1]);
  TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
    locations[0], 0.0f, locations[1], 0.0f);
  translateAnimation.setDuration(10000);
  imgSample.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
 }